# Does an assignment of a real to a variable starting with I convert to integer?

Tags: fortran

Does an assignment of a real to a variable starting with I convert to integer?

```
real vx;
vx = 2.59808
ix = vx
```

is ix == 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the type will be automatically converted.

You can turn of this error-prone behavior by specifying

```
IMPLICIT NONE
```

The "implicit none" statement forces the programmer to declare all variables. Otherwise the types will just be implicit and variables starting with `i` will be of type integer.

Answer (score -1):

as far as i know you need to cast real into integer.

but i not sure, if it is allowed in your language.